# update kivy label using screen manager

Tags: python, label, refresh, screen, kivy

Im trying to make a multi screen app and I want a date/time label on all of them. 
I made a clock event that update the text value each second.

The clock event is working because on python console I can see it updating, but the label is not refreshing,  it just works the first time.
How can I refresh the screen?

The main.py file:

```
import kivy
import time
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock

kivy.require("1.9.1")
Window.size = (1280,1024)
Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', '0')

class TimeLabel(Label):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TimeLabel, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.text= str(time.asctime())

    def update(self, *args):
        self.text = str(time.asctime())
        print self.text


class LoginScreen(Screen):
    pass


class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass


class My1App(App):
    def build(self):
        my1sm = Builder.load_file("main.kv")
        crudeclock = TimeLabel()
        Clock.schedule_interval(crudeclock.update, 1)
        return my1sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    My1App().run()
```

and the main.kv file:

```
#: kivy 1.9
#: import ScreenManager kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManager
#: import Screen kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManager
#: import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition

ScreenManagement:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    MainScreen:
    LoginScreen:


<MainScreen>:
    name: 'main'
    size_hint: (1, 1)
    FloatLayout:
        Image:
            source: './background.png'
            size: 1280,1024
    TimeLabel:


<LoginScreen>:
    name: 'loginS'
    FloatLayout:
        Image:
            source: './Login.png'
            size: 1280,1024
    TimeLabel:


<TimeLabel>:
    x:-545
    y:-475
    color: (0,0,0,1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the schedule_interval when the label is instantiated.

```
import kivy
import time
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock

kivy.require("1.9.1")
Window.size = (600,600)
Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', '0')

class TimeLabel(Label):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TimeLabel, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.text= str(time.asctime())
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update,1)

    def update(self, *args):
        self.text = str(time.asctime())
        print self.text


class LoginScreen(Screen):
    pass


class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass


class My1App(App):
    def build(self):
        my1sm = Builder.load_file("main.kv")
        crudeclock = TimeLabel()
        return my1sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    My1App().run()
```